# QMK setup fails with "No Module named hid"

Tags: python, qmk, qmk-firmware

I'm attempting to get [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm) working. After installing via `brew install qmk/qmk/qmk/`, I run `qmk setup`.

I get this error.

```
qmk setup
```

Output:

```
Error: %s: %s ('ModuleNotFoundError', ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'hid'"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/qmk/0.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qmk_cli/script_qmk.py", line 99, in main
    import qmk.cli  # noqa
  File "/Users/anthony/qmk_firmware/lib/python/qmk/cli/__init__.py", line 158, in <module>
    from . import console  # noqa
  File "/Users/anthony/qmk_firmware/lib/python/qmk/cli/console.py", line 9, in <module>
    import hid
```

I'm on [macOS v10.15.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina). I have Python installed via pyenv. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: have you tried to install it manually, like `/usr/local/Cellar/qmk/0.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.9 -m pip install hid`?

Comment: In a way. That directory actually had a bunch of what appeared to be source files. Python was installed into `/usr/local/Cellar/qmk/0.0.45/libexec/bin/python3.9`. Doing so is successful but gives another error:

Error: %s: %s ('ImportError', ImportError('Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll'))
. . .

Comment: have you tried to install [libhid](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libhid) then?

Comment: it all looks strange, have you tried to install `qmk` by simply using `/path/to/python -m pip install qmk`?

Comment: Turns out `qmk` had an issue that is resolved by upgrading to at least 0.0.51

Comment: Hi I always start with qmk doctor - it checks environment.
In my case it was many other dependencies, after running everything worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating QMK. I had the same issue with 0.0.45, but it worked with 0.0.51.

Try `brew upgrade qmk/qmk/qmk`.